# Avoiding image cropping and casting it to a fixed image size

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imageview

I'm trying to create an image of size 720*1280 resolution from images greater or smaller than this size without cropping and distorting it. If height or width or both become smaller while doing so fill a color in the blank area. First image to the second image.
[image: Initial_Image] [image: Final_Final Image]

I tried this but could not get the desired result and no any idea about color picking.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/action_image"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="720dp"
    android:layout_height="1280dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

//try this code with picasso library

```
int finalHeight, finalWidth;
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
    Picasso.with(context).load("url").resize(iv.getMeasuredWidth(), iv.getMeasuredHeight()).into(imageView);
            return true; 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The scaleType `fitXY` may distort your image. Use scaleType `fitCenter` with a background color of your choice.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="720dp"
    android:layout_height="1280dp"
    android:background="#0f0"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/sample_good_perfect" />
```